# Android does not pick up strings.xml from Any Region (for ex.values_zh) specifically for locale zh_US

Tags: android, localization, locale, android-resources, android-resource-qualifiers

I have 2 module projects (lets say **App1** and **App2**) into the same repo, both apps have **values_zh**, **values-zh-rTW** and **values-zh-rHK** in their respective **src>res** folders.

When I set a custom locale of the device to **zh_US** (on rooted device/emulator) then the **App1** picks up **string.xml** from **values_zh** but **App2** is picking from **values-zh-rTW** instead of **values-zh**.

But if I add **values-zh-rUS** to **App2** then it pick it from there. I wanted it to pick up from **values-zh** (Since US can fall in to Any Region).

**Note :** if I set the custom locale to **zh_CA** then both **App1** and **App2** picks up **string.xml** from **values-zh** (Any region). Why is this specific problem for **zh_US** and the differences in 2 apps (Trying to understand if any code is responsible for it. I guess Android system should pick the correct strings.xml as per my understanding. Need clarification). Any Idea, please suggest. TIA.

I have already gone through below Android documentation but did not find explanation for above.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html