# Use one file strings.xml for different resources folders

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I have 3 folders for Norwegian languages but I only have 1 file for translations.

```
/values-no/
/values-nn/
/values-nb/
```

For now I have the same `strings.xml` triplicated, one in every folder.

**Could I link the resources of some folders to another one?**
**Any other solution?**

Edit: 
I want to avoid to have the same file 3 times in the final .apk

Comment: What about creating a softlink ?

Comment: Another approach is to add a gradle task that copies one string.xml from one location, to the other folders.

Answer (score 1):

If it's your own application, you could probably use this trick to merge all 3 locales:

```
Locale locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
if (locale.getLanguage().equals("no") || locale.getLanguage().equals("nb") || locale.getLanguage().equals("nn")){
    locale = new Locale("no","NO");
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    Resources res = getBaseContext().getResources();
    res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18236011/3071215)